# C# get a http response from another class method

Tags: c#

Previously i handled all my http requests in a single class but i would like to move the http login functionality to a different class but now i cant access the http client `response.IsSuccessStatusCode`

this is my original code whic works

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var url = String.Format(shared.AppDetails.domainurl+"/v2auth/default/login");
var response2 = await http.PostAsync(url, credentials);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //do after login stuff
}
```

Now i would like to move the login logic to a different class that is in a different folder(auth->dbhelpers)

```
class LoginHttp
{
    public static async Task<object> loginAsync(String username, String password)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "username",username },
            { "password", password }
        };
        var credentials = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format(shared.AppDetails.domainurl + "/v2auth/default/login");
        var response = await http.PostAsync(url, credentials);

        return response;
    }  
}
```

So am now trying to access the returned response via

```
var responsefromhttplogin = auth.dbhelpers.AuthHttp.loginAsync(login_username.Text, login_password.Password);
if (responsefromhttplogin .IsSuccessStatusCode) //this fails
{
    //do after login stuff
}
```

How can i get the retrned response be of type HttpClient again?
Am getting an error of

```
Task<Objct> does not contain defination for IsSuccessStatusCode
```

Comment: What does `//this fails` mean? Do you get an exception? Do you get any other HttpStatusCode back?

Comment: I have updted the error code thrown by visual studio which is IsSuccessStatusCode

Comment: try using `responsefromhttplogin = await ...;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your loginAsync method return Task instead. Currently you are returning an object, then you will have access to the IsSuccessStatusCode

```
class LoginHttp{
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> loginAsync(String username, String password)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
          { "username",username },
          { "password", password }
        };
    var credentials = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var http = new HttpClient();
    var url = String.Format(shared.AppDetails.domainurl + "/v2auth/default/login");
    var response = await http.PostAsync(url, credentials);

    return response;
}
```

}

You also need to use await in your calling method, otherwise you get a Task back

```
    var responsefromhttplogin = await auth.dbhelpers.AuthHttp.loginAsync(login_username.Text, login_password.Password);
if (responsefromhttplogin.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //do after login stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to await async method like this:

```
var responsefromhttplogin = await auth.dbhelpers.AuthHttp.loginAsync(login_username.Text, login_password.Password);
if (responsefromhttplogin.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   //do after login stuff
}
```

Now after you add await this `responsefromhttplogin.IsSuccessStatusCode` should be accessible.

And also change your method to return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` instead of `Task<object>`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `Task<object>` from `loginAsync()`, to access the result of the task you can use `Task.Result`.

I would consider to narrow down the type that you are returning from `object` to `HttpResponseMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, you are returning a `Task<object>`

You should either cast the `return response;` as `return (HttpResponseMessage) response;`

Or change the return type to be `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

[Relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx)